# Python36 Discord Bot: Task was destroyed but it is pending

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

When I run my bot, I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timestamps'
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
```

I will post the full code (excluding the bot token) so someone can help me find this issue.  Basically, this bot, for a long time, was working perfectly, and went through various different versions that never had any issues before.  I would usually make a simple error and have to fix it.  However, I use another discord bot's dependency batch code to automatically grab the plugins and their latest versions.  I think when either Discord, Python, or some other plugin updated, and it caused this issue that broke the current code.

The link to my discord bot's code is here:
https://pastebin.com/Sp8jjSDb

**Note**: The client.Close() at the end is new, and a test to see if it would fix the issue.  I didn't originally need that to be there.

Here is the full debug log for whoever is interested:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\MusicBot_2\app.py", line 1027, in <module>
    client.run('[TOKEN HIDDEN]')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\discord\client.py", line 519, in run
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 466, in run_
until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\discord\client.py", line 491, in start
    yield from self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\discord\client.py", line 448, in connect
    yield from self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\discord\gateway.py", line 431, in poll_eve
nt
    yield from self.received_message(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\discord\gateway.py", line 390, in received
_message
    func(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\discord\state.py", line 509, in parse_guil
d_create
    server = self._get_create_server(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\discord\state.py", line 483, in _get_creat
e_server
    server._from_data(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\discord\server.py", line 218, in _from_dat
a
    self._sync(guild)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\discord\server.py", line 245, in _sync
    member.game = Game(**game) if game else None
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timestamps'
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<ConnectionState._delay_ready() running at C:\Program F
iles\Python36\lib\discord\state.py:173> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeup
MethWrapper object at 0x0000000003B83108>()]>>
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I was running a newer version of Python, which for some reason causes errors with the bot.  This can be fixed by forcing it to run 'python35' instead of a later version.